# Some text on Windows 10 UI appears as boxes

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, user-interface, microsoft-surface

I have been recently experiencing an issue where some text/buttons on the Windows 10 user interface appears as empty rectangular boxes.

[image]

[image]

I have tried the following already:

- Switching between languages in the settings app.
- Resetting fonts to default settings in control panel.
- Restarting the device does not fix the problem.

Device Specs:

- Device: Surface Pro 6
- OS: Windows 10 1909
- CPU: i5-8250U
- RAM: 8GB
- STORAGE: 256 GB SSD

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen it personally on Windows, but a similar issue can occur on Macs. The fix is to do an 'over the top' system reinstall [without affecting installs & files]. Windows *might* be able to fix it from cmd: `sfc /scannow` or from DISM, but I'm not certain, hence just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The missing text is likely due to a missing font. One reason that can happen is that installation might have been done by another user, e.g. Administrator, and some parts of the installation were not for the system, but for the user. Does the issue disappear if run as Admin?

Comment: What language is your system set to? This sounds like a localisation issue.

Comment: @Burgi its set to English (Australia) however I seemed to have fixed the issue by running an in place upgrade (via windows 10 creation tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `sfc /scannow` or `DISM` did not detect any issues. Instead I have done an in-place upgrade (via the Windows 10 Media Creation tool and selecting "Upgrade this PC now" and keeping all files and apps) which has now seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: Glad you got it from my rather vague, Mac-based guess :)